# Installing PhpMyAdmin on Local Machine to Access AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have a Database configured with Amazon Web Services RDS.  I want to access PhpMyAdmin to control it.

I understand doing this in the config file:

```
/*
* AWS RDS server
*/
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'HTTP';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '(mysql|information_schema|phpmyadmin)';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '------.rds.amazonaws.com';
```

My question is, I have a WAMP setup on my Home  computer.  Can I use this to access (remotely) the Amazon MySQL Database?  Or do I have to use the Amazon Cloud Services to host PhpMyAdmin files?

Supplemental:  If I CAN do it on my home WAMP server, are there other config params I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but there are better clients than phpmyadmin if you are going to connect from your desktop. For Windows I prefer SQLyog, but you can find numerous free and commercial mysql clients.

To connect, you will need to open the security group to your IP address. This can be a bit of a pain if you are not on a static IP address. You may have to update the security group each time you want to connect.

Comment: Hey thanks... Opening the group to my IP seems to be where I was going wrong!